# JSP pass Variable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have to write a website with JSP and Servlets which displays a questionnaire and gets the result of the user.

I've already written the question object, a questionnaire (random list of questions) and the questions library.

Now my Servlet generates an instance of the questionnaire and displays the questions. My problem is I don't know how to get the results. I can get the answers but AFAIK every time I load a Servlet it would generate a new questionnaire and the answers would be useless. So how can I pass the answers to the correct questionnaire. Or how can I pass the questionnaire to my new Servlet?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: Here is the code for the questionnaire:

```
public abstract Question getNextQuestion();

public abstract void setResult(ArrayList<Boolean> answers);

public abstract int[] getResult();
```

Basically I create a questionnaire, and get via `getNextQuestion()` the next question until there are no more. then the user will hit the submit button and i'll have to read the answers and pass it to the questionnaire (`setResult()` for the actual question). When there is no more question I'll use `retResult()` for the result.

Hope this helps. I can't give u any JSP code since I have no JSP written yet

Comment: Some sample code would be helpful in understanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating a questionnaire per user when he enters the site you can have the servlet generate tehe questionnaire and record it into the session under a name like "lastGeneratedQuestionnaire".

When the answers are submitted that servlet would retrieve the questionnaire from the session by that name. If one is not there I would redirect the user back to the page that generates a new questionnaire.

Also, the page that generates a new questionnaire should override the object in the session each time it generates a random questionnaire.

The short of it is...use the HttpSession to store the object between requests.

Answer (score 1):

Any data which must survive several requests should go into the session (see `request.getSession()`).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you will have a form object (on the JSP page) that will be associated with your questionaire.

```
<html:form action="/servlets/MyQuestionaireServlet method="post">
    <h3>Question 1: What is your name</h3>
    <html:text name="question1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

What you need to do in order to send the data to the servlet so that it can be stored/recorded is you need to provide a submit button inside of the form.  This will send all of the data in the form to the servlet.

Good point, without struts you can still perform a standard post method on the form and retrieve the values in the servlet listed under action.  You do not need struts to perform an action on a form.

Comment: The OP didn't said he was using Struts.

Comment: no i'm not using stuts. it's actually the first time i'm using jsp ;)